# reusing a used usb thumbdrive which formerly had a Xubuntu live system on it

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, format, fdisk

I have an USB thumbdrive (16 GiB) which I recovered after I had a Xubuntu live system on it. First I wanted to change the partitions on it with gparted, but that did not work: The driver descriptor told that the physical blocksize was 2048 Bytes, however Linux told it were 512 Bytes.

I got out of this trouble by using sudo fdisk /dev/sdb1. Then I used the commands g, F, n, p, w of fdisk.

After this, stick still was not as I wanted it to be: there was an unknown file system on it. At least the thumbdrive had become accessible to gparted. Therefore I partitioned the thumbdrive anew and made a big fat32-partition with the partition name WinBoot on it, since I want to use it to make it a Windows bootstick. After I had defined the partition layout with 9 MiB unassigned at the beginning and another 9 MiB unassigned at the end and everything else in between one big fat32 partition. I clicked on the green hook to have it patitioned and formatted.

Now blkid tells about this thumbdrive

/dev/sdb1: UUID="B242-0351" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="WinBoot" PARTUUID="8025f481-3d3e-4038-a57b-f32200c5cfa7"

However, if I attach this thumbdrive to my computer, it mounts as

/media/username/Xubuntu 18.04.3 LTS amd64/

Thunar displays this directory as empty, as expected. Formerly, there was a Xubuntu 18.04.3 live system on this stick. But how does Xubuntu 16.04 (the operating system version with which this happens) know what was on the stick before? Why does it not mount it as /media/user/WinBoot?

What must I do to get rid of the old livestick name and let it automatically mount as /media/user/WinBoot?

Comment: Does `sudo fatlabel /dev/sdb1` give a useful output?

Comment: Drives can have Names and Labels, and Names NEQ Labels (and vice versa).

Comment: Is this an useful output:$ sudo fatlabel /dev/sdb1
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
           
$